# Dependency injection in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am trying to use dependency injection in my Spring MVC web application. I have a function like this in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stockgoogle/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Stock stockGoogle(Locale locale, Model model) {    
    StockDaoImpl si = new StockDaoImpl();
    //al=s.listCurrent(id);
    Stock s=si.listGoogle();
    System.out.println("reached here");
    model.addAttribute("s", s );        
    return s;
}
```

I want to dependency inject StockDaoImpl. Can you please tell me how I can do this. I have been trying to read but most of the explainations are very complex. Should I use @Autowired ? Where should I put it? Can you please help.

Comment: If most explanations are very complex, you won't get any better here. Read the Spring documentation. This is the most basic and important concept of Spring.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject it through the Controller's constructor

```
class YourController{

  private final StockDao dao;

  @Autowired 
  public YourController(StockDao dao){
    this.dao = dao;
  }
}
```

And now `StockDaoImpl` has to be defined as a `Bean` of course,

```
@Bean
public StockDao stockDao(){
  return new StockDaoImpl();
}
```

Another way for doing it would be defining `StockDaoImpl` as a `Component`

Comment: Hi Sleiman, thank you for your answer. I will do this. Do I have to change anything else? In this controller method?

Comment: no, but start using this.dao rather than instantiating it directly

Comment: I am sorry, just to clarify. Where should I put the StockDao() method? StockDao is my interface and StockDaoImpl class is the implementation.

Comment: No matching bean of type [com.sachin.dao.StockDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.sachin.dao.StockDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: @sachinsrivastava you can put it in your configuration class

Answer (score 0):

Add below config in Spring config file(for example root-context.xml)

then in your controller, you like below code

class TestController{

@Autowired
private StockDao stockDao;

}

Answer (score 0):

> With spring-4 you can directly inject in given way **:**

```
@Autowired
private StockDao stockDao;

public @ResponseBody Stock stockGoogle(Locale locale, Model model) {    

    //al=s.listCurrent(id);
    Stock s = stockDao.listGoogle();
    System.out.println("reached here");
    model.addAttribute("s", s );        
    return s;

}
```

Here

- StockDao will contain method signature
- StockDaoImpl implements StockDao and definition of methods
- Autowired will inject that Dao and you can use its method.